# Copiar datos específicos desde un fichero de texto a otros ficheros en C

Tags: c, archivo, texto

A partir de un fichero.txt necesito copiar en dos ficheros diferentes las personas mayores y menores de 50 años. Solo consigo que se me copien en un solo fichero y no encuentro el error. La función es la siguiente:

```
void separa(const char * fichero, const char * menores, const char * mayores){
    FILE * f, * men, * may;
    f=fopen(fichero, "r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("ERROR al abrir el fichero");
        exit(-1);
    }
    men=fopen(menores, "a");
    if(men==NULL){
        printf("ERROR al abrir el fichero");
        exit(-1);
    }
    may=fopen(mayores, "a");
    if(may==NULL){
        printf("ERROR al abrir el fichero");
        exit(-1);
    }
    Persona aux;
    while((fscanf(f, "%s\n%i\n", aux.nombre, &aux.edad))!=EOF){
        int age = fscanf(f, "%i", &aux.edad);
        if(age<50){
            fprintf(men, "%s\n%i\n", aux.nombre, aux.edad);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(may, "%s\n%i\n", aux.nombre, aux.edad);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(men);
    fclose(may);
}
```

Comment: Podrias quitar esta linea `int age = fscanf(f, "%i", &aux.edad);` y poner unos prints para las variables `aux.nombre` y `aux.edad` para ver que datos esta recuperando, porfa? Y mientras en el if ponlo asi `if(aux.edad<50)`

Comment: Pues justo era ese el simple error en el que llevaba todo el día trabado. Poniendo el if tal y como me has dicho funciona todo correctamente. Aunque no entiendo del todo cual es la diferencia respecto al código original, funciona. Gracias ;)

Comment: Dejo abajo la solución y la respuesta a tu duda para que le des el visto bueno. No hay de que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respeto al comentario que te he dejado, aquí esta el código final

```
void separa(const char * fichero, const char * menores, const char * mayores){
    FILE * f, * men, * may;
    f=fopen(fichero, "r");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("ERROR al abrir el fichero");
        exit(-1);
    }
    men=fopen(menores, "a");
    if(men==NULL){
        printf("ERROR al abrir el fichero");
        exit(-1);
    }
    may=fopen(mayores, "a");
    if(may==NULL){
        printf("ERROR al abrir el fichero");
        exit(-1);
    }
    Persona aux;
    while((fscanf(f, "%s\n%i\n", aux.nombre, &aux.edad))!=EOF){
        if(aux.edad<50){
            fprintf(men, "%s\n%i\n", aux.nombre, aux.edad);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(may, "%s\n%i\n", aux.nombre, aux.edad);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(men);
    fclose(may);
}
```

Y con respecto a tu duda, lo que pasa es que cuando estas leyendo un archivo, este no lee todas las líneas al mismo tiempo, es decir, va de arriba hacia abajo leyendo linea por linea, por eso tu `while` , el while lo que hace ahí es estar leyendo cada linea y asignarle dicho valor a la estructura `aux` de tipo **Persona** , entonces lo hace hasta el fin que obtenga un valor `EOF` lo que significa *end of file*.
Entonces una vez dicho eso, lo que estabas haciendo era leer el archivo en la clausula `while` con un `fscanf` cada vez que dicha linea sea diferente de `EOF`(lo que significa que ya leíste una linea por primera vez), después hacías otro `scanf` al archivo (significa que ibas a leer una nueva linea, no que ibas a buscar el valor entero de la linea que leiste en la clausula `while`) lo cual iba a causar error, ya que el valor que seguia de la siguiente linea es un `%s` segun la estructura de tu archivo.